# I can't add new data to mysql, though I can manipulate existing (imported) data

Tags: python, django

I am struggling for 5 days, cant make it work. My code works perfectly fine on local server, but wont work when i upload application. It just won't accept any new data i just face some weird redirections to homepaage with the url of the page i made submit. The existing(imported) data can be manipulated and changed, just no way to submit new data.

```html
{% extends "baza.html" %}

{% block content %}
{% load static %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
<div class="container-login100" style="background-image: url('/static/images/pticica.jpg');">
  <div class="wrap-login100">
    <form  method="POST" action="{% url 'Registracija' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="login100-form">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <span class="login100-form-logo">
        <i class="zmdi zmdi-landscape">
          <img style="border-radius:100%;padding:5px;" src="/static/images/login.png">
        </i>
      </span>
      <span class="login100-form-title p-b-34 p-t-27">Registruj se</span>
      {{form|crispy}}
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Registruj se</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

my views

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forme import RegisterForm
def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():

            form.save()
        return redirect("login")

    else:
        form=RegisterForm()
        return render(request,"register/register.html", {'form':form})
```

and global settings

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
import os
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/{{ docs_version }}/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '{{ secret_key }}'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['ljubimac.me','www.ljubimac.me']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = ['Websajt',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'register',
    'crispy_forms',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account' ,
    'allauth.socialaccount' ,
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.github',
    'Users',

                  ]

SITE_ID = 1

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',

    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'Sajt.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'Sajt.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/{{ docs_version }}/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'deniggsm_ljubimac',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'USER': 'deniggsm_Andrija_Culafic',
        'PASSWORD':'protokol123',
        'PORT': '3306',

    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/{{ docs_version }}/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/{{ docs_version }}/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'sr'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
LOCALE_PATHS=[
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'locale')
]

STATIC_URL=('/static/')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

#email
EMAIL_HOST='smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT='465'
EMAIL_HOST_USER="selastan@gmail.com"
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD="extractor361"
EMAIL_USE_SSL="True"
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'noreply<no_reply@domain.com>'

SITE_ID = 1

MEDIA_ROOT =  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL='/'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL='/login'
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/media/'

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'Users.NewUser'
```

url patterns

```
    from django.urls import include,path
from . import views
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from register.views import register
from django.conf import settings



urlpatterns = [
path('',views.Naslovna,name='Naslovna'),
path('postavi-oglas/',views.Oglasss,name='Oglasss'),
path('svi-oglasi/<slug:slug>/',views.Pojedinacni_Oglas,name='Pojedinacni'),

path('svi-oglasi',views.Sviii,name='Svi_Oglasi'),
path('svi-oglasi/sortiranje',views.Sortiranje,name='Sortiranje'),
path('registracija/',register,name="Registracija"),
path('admin/',admin.site.urls),
path('moj-profil',views.MojProfil,name='Profil'),
path('promijeni-lozinku/',views.PromijeniSifru,name="Lozinka"),
path('kategorije/',views.Kategorije,name="Kategorijaaa"),
path('Psi/',views.Psi,name="Psiii"),
path('Mačke/',views.Mačke,name="Mačkeee"),
path('Ptice/',views.Ptice,name="Pticeee"),
path('Reptili/',views.Reptili,name="Reptiliii"),
path('Ribice/',views.Ribice,name="Ribiceee"),
path('Glodari/',views.Glodari,name="Glodariii"),

]
```

url.py in root

```
from django.urls import include,path
from django.contrib import admin

from django.conf.urls import include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf.urls.static import static
urlpatterns = [
path('',include('Websajt.urls')),
              path('',include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),]
urlpatterns+=static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

edited register view

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forme import RegisterForm
def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():

            form.save()
            print(form.errors)
            return redirect("login")

    else:
        form=RegisterForm()
    return render(request,"register/register.html", {'form':form})
```

Comment: You are redirecting even if `form.is_valid()` evaluates to `False`. Try writing `print(form.errors)` just before that `return redirect("login")`, what does it give you?

Comment: I am not sure how to see printed errors on my virtualenviroment. I added the code, but nothing happens.

Comment: Do this, increase the indent of `return redirect("login")` so it is inside the `if form.is_valid():` block, and decrease the indent of the `return render(request,"register/register.html", {'form':form})` so that it is outside the `else` block but still in the view. Now you should be rendered the page back with the form errors, what errors do you get?

Comment: Nothing happens, it still redirects me to homepage with register(registracija) in my url. Like ljubimac.me/Registracija, but i am on my homepage

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add your url patterns to it, also show your edited view code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233391/discussion-between-andrija-culafic-and-abdul-aziz-barkat).